# Uniqueness of sharedUserId in Android

Tags: android, security

If you don't set a `sharedUserId` in Android, a unique one is automatically assigned to the application, according to the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html).

But in what way is the `sharedUserId` unique? Is it only unique to the application, i.e. does an application have the same `sharedUserId` on all devices? This would mean that you can find it out for one installation programatically and use that value for a second app.

Or is the ID a random value that is different on every single device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But in what way is the sharedUserId unique?

All Linux user accounts are unique. `android:sharedUserId` says that 2+ apps, signed by the same signing key, should share a Linux user account. By default, they each get their own Linux user account.

> does an application have the same sharedUserId on all devices?

It has the same `android:sharedUserId` value wherever you choose to use it. The Linux user account, though, will be different for different devices.

> Or is the ID a random value that is different on every single device?

I wouldn't say "random", as I do not know the precise algorithm that is used to choose the number.

Comment: Thank you! I don't "choose to use it" anywhere, I'm talking about the automatically assigned one. Is this ID different on all devices or does Android assign the same automatically generated ID to all installations of a given app?

Comment: @MarcoW.: "I'm talking about the automatically assigned one" -- there is no automatically assigned `android:sharedUserId`. Please note the use of the word "shared" in `sharedUserId`. That can only be opted into by you as a developer.

Comment: Okay, you're right. I actually wanted to refer to the app's Linux user ID. Is this, if automatically assigned, always the same for one application across devices or random?

Comment: @MarcoW.: From your standpoint, it is "random", insofar as it will not be the same user ID on different devices.